# Shortest path LP formulation : reverse links taking on value 1

Tags: python-3.x, shortest-path, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to implement an ILP formulation of the shortest path problem using the PuLP package in python. The input is a graph generated using the NetworkX package.

```
import networkx as nx
import pulp
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.to_directed(nx.barabasi_albert_graph(20, 2))
# nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
# plt.show()
source = 0
target = 13

dict_d = {}
for i, j in g.edges:
    dict_d[i, j] = dict_d[j, i] = round(random.uniform(1.0, 20.0), 2)

nx.set_edge_attributes(g, dict_d, 'delay')

# instantiate
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Shortest Path Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)
cost = nx.get_edge_attributes(g, 'delay')

# binary variable to state a link is chosen or not
var_dict = {}
for (i, j) in g.edges:
    x = pulp.LpVariable("x_(%s_%s)" % (i,j), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    var_dict[i, j] = x

# objective function
prob += pulp.lpSum([cost[i, j] * var_dict[i, j] for i, j in g.edges]), "Total Hop Count"

# constraints
for node in g.nodes:
    if node == source:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([var_dict[i, k] for i, k in g.edges if k == node]) - \
                pulp.lpSum([var_dict[k, j] for k, j in g.edges if k == node]) == 1
    elif node == target:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([var_dict[i, k] for i, k in g.edges if k == node]) - \
                pulp.lpSum([var_dict[k, j] for k, j in g.edges if k == node]) == -1
    else:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([var_dict[i, k] for i, k in g.edges if k == node]) - \
                pulp.lpSum([var_dict[k, j] for k, j in g.edges if k == node]) == 0

# solve
prob.solve(pulp.GUROBI_CMD(msg=0))

print(pulp.LpStatus[prob.status])
print(pulp.value(prob.objective))
print("The shortest path is ")
for link in g.edges:
    if var_dict[link].value() == 1.0:
        print(link, end=" ")
```

If I use an undirected graph, the conservation of flow constraint does not work since the reverse edge is not present in the graph.

```
prob += pulp.lpSum([var_dict[i, k] for i, k in g.edges if k == node]) - \
                pulp.lpSum([var_dict[k, j] for k, j in g.edges if k == node]) == 1
```

On the other hand, while using directed graphs, the indicator variables of the reverse edge takes on values, leading to output

```
The shortest path is (1, 2) (2, 0) (13, 1)
```

when output should be (0,2) (2,1) (1,13)

So my question is two-pronged:

1. Is there a better representation of the LP formulation for the shortest path problem that avoids this problem altogether?
2. Failing that, how to get a meaningful path as output? Stop the reverse arcs from taking on values? Get a path somehow from the output I am getting now?

Comment: If you ask about formulation, please write it down instead of code, otherwise it is a debugging exercise.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it in mind. Actually, I was not sure if the error was in the formulation or due to some mistake in the way I had represented it in PuLP syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use an undirected graph, the conservation of flow constraint does
>   not work since the reverse edge is not present in the graph.

This is not true: I used `prob.writeLP('eyes.lp')` to check the balance constraints, and it seems that the reverse edges are present.

> On the other hand, while using directed graphs, the indicator
>   variables of the reverse edge takes on values, leading to output
>
> ```
> The shortest path is (1, 2) (2, 0) (13, 1)
> ```
>
> when output should be (0,2) (2,1) (1,13)

The problem here is that the signs of the source and the target constraints are flipped: notice that your solution goes from target to source instead of source to target. If you change the signs, it will work correctly:

```
# constraints
for node in g.nodes:
    rhs = 0
    if node == source:
        rhs = -1
    elif node == target:
        rhs = 1
    prob += pulp.lpSum([var_dict[i, k] for i, k in g.edges if k == node]) - \
            pulp.lpSum([var_dict[k, j] for k, j in g.edges if k == node]) == rhs
```

> Is there a better representation of the LP formulation for the
>   shortest path problem that avoids this problem altogether?

The LP formulation is correct.

> Failing that, how to get a meaningful path as output? Stop the reverse
>   arcs from taking on values? Get a path somehow from the output I am
>   getting now?

Fixing the signs should make it work.